# DropZone.js uploading is not working on programmatically

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

I am working on dropzone js programmatically. this is My div,

```
<div class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"> 
    <div class="dz-message">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="message">
                <p>Drop files here or Click to Upload</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fallback">
        <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
    </div>
</div>
```

and rpzone class is
// Dropzone class:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#my-dropzone", { url: "/file/post"});
```

but when I drag and drop images to dropzone box images are preview with cross symbols (not success upload). then how can I fix this problem? 
dropzone.confif.js

```
var total_photos_counter = 0;
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 2,
    maxFilesize: 5,
    previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview').innerHTML,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove file',
    dictFileTooBig: 'Image is larger than 16MB',
    timeout: 10000,

    init: function () {
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
            $.post({
                url: '/images-delete',
                data: {id: file.name, _token: $('[name="_token"]').val()},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    total_photos_counter--;
                    $("#counter").text("# " + total_photos_counter);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    success: function (file, done) {
        total_photos_counter++;
        $("#counter").text("# " + total_photos_counter);
    }
};
```

Comment: no any idea to solve this matter?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: No any errors in the console

Comment: with following form tag **<form method="post" action="{{ url('/images-save') }}"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">
                {{ csrf_field() }}** it is working fine but with div it is not working....

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using the first snippet `new Dropzone()`? the second snippet `Dropzone.options.myDropzone =`? or both?

Comment: both using......

Answer (score 0):

after long time spending find the solution. problem is {{ csrf_field() }} not configuring in my div tag,
first Add this to your main blade template in the  section:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and then configure dropzone.config.js file to csrf

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 2,
    maxFilesize: 16,
    previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview').innerHTML,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove file',
    dictFileTooBig: 'Image is larger than 16MB',
    timeout: 10000,

    init: function () {
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
            $.post({
                url: '/images-delete',
                data: {id: file.name, _token: $('[name="_token"]').val()},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    total_photos_counter--;
                    $("#counter").text("# " + total_photos_counter);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    success: function (file, done) {
        total_photos_counter++;
        $("#counter").text("# " + total_photos_counter);
    },

    sending: function(file, xhr, formData){
        formData.append('_token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    }
};
```

now it is working fine with correct url